# What causes "Variable does not exist in current context" message

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write a very simple C# program in VS2015. I keep getting a message "The name (variable) does not exist in the current context."  This is true for both my bool variable and string variable.

```
    namespace PTouch
{
    public class PTouch
    {
        bool lb_rc;
        string strLabel;
        lb_rc = false;
        strLabel = "C:\BenchTop10\Standard 1in.lbx";
        bpac.Document doc = new Document();
        lb_rc = doc.Open("C:\BenchTop10\Standard 1in.lbx");
        if lb_rc != false
        {
            doc.StartPrint("", 0);
            doc.PrintOut(1, 0);
            doc.EndPrint();
            doc.Close();
         }
         else
         {
                MessageBox.Show("Open Error: " + doc.ErrorCode);
         }
    }
}
```

There are probably several problems with this code, but the first one is error about the variables not existing in the current context.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Chagne `if lb_rc != false` to `if (lb_rc != false)` and see what your errors change to.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  The error is on the line that sets lb_rc = false;  I tried initializing lb_rc in the declaration:  bool lb_rc =  false;  No luck.  Same thing is true with string strLabel;

Comment: I just discovered the problem... All the code has to be inside of a method, not just the class.  I added a method to the class,         public void PrintLabel()
        { bool lb_rc;
          ...
         }
All errors cleared up, except MessageBox...

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the problem... All the code has to be inside of a method, not just the class. I added a method to the class,
public void PrintLabel()
{ bool lb_rc; ... }

All errors cleared up, except MessageBox...
Thank you,
Tracy